# MS Access RunLoop=false in other forms

Tags: forms, loops, ms-access

how can i stop a loop in another form?
I am running a loop in formA and i want it to stop when a button in Form B is clicked.
is this possible?
Kind Regards-

i tried [forms!FormA!Runloop=False

Comment: Afraid not. Need a condition within the loop that when met will cause loop to terminate. Such as when an incremented number variable hits a specified limit. Cannot be any input by user.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible communicate between forms, using public members of form. Please see example.
In FormB:

```
Private Sub cmStopLongLoop_Click()
Dim res As String
    res = SetStopLongLoop("FormA")
    Call MsgBox(res)
End Sub

Private Function SetStopLongLoop(pFormName As String) As String
Dim frm As Form
Dim i As Long
Dim res As String
Dim isForm As Boolean
    isForm = False
    With Forms ' check for form is loaded and not in design mode
    For i = 0 To .Count - 1
        If .Item(i).Name = pFormName Then
            If Forms(i).CurrentView > 0 Then
                isForm = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    End With
    If Not isForm Then
       res = "Form " & pFormName & " is not loaded"
    Else
        Set frm = Forms(pFormName)
        frm.NeedStopLongLoop = True
        If Not frm.LongLoopIsRunning Then
            res = "LongLoop Is not running"
        Else
            res = "LongLoop Is set to stop"
        End If
    End If
    SetStopLongLoop = res
End Function
```

In FormA: declare 2 `public` members. First to set signal to stop process. Second to indicate Loop is running.

```
Public NeedStopLongLoop As Boolean
Public LongLoopIsRunning As Boolean

Private Sub cmRanLongLoop_Click()
    LongLoopIsRunning = True
    NeedStopLongLoop = False
    Call RunLongLoop
    LongLoopIsRunning = False
End Sub

Private Sub RunLongLoop()
Dim i As Long
Dim xlApp As Object
    For i = 1 To 100   ' this is long circle
        'some long calculations
        DoEvents 'simple pause for other forms to reacts to mouse click 
        If NeedStopLongLoop Then
            Call MsgBox("Long loop is stoped")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```